# On Jupyter Pandas.read_csv() is taking too much time [1 hr] in reading a 3GB csv file on virtual machine (debian 64 bit) but not on local [1 min ]

Tags: pandas, csv, memory, jupyter, large-data

A csv file of size 3 GB when read to a pandas dataframe on Jupyter using  `pandas.read_csv("filename.csv")` is taking 1 min when jupyter is on local machine [8 GB RAM, i5 Processor, 64 bit, Windows OS ]. But when i move the file and the jupyter to a virtual machine with configuration [ 10 GB RAM, 100 GB disk, Debian OS, 64 bit machine, Pandas(1.4.2), Jupyter_core(4.9.2) and Python(3.9.12) ], the file reading is taking more than 1 hour.

I am creating a dataframe out of the csv file. The csv file has around 12M rows. I checked and found that the csv file of size 3GB is taking 6-7GB of size in memory.

Question: Why is it taking so much time in loading the CSV to dataframe on VM and is there a faster way to do this ?

Let me know if any other information is required

I tried reading the csv in chunks which was faster to read but was taking around 6 GB in memory. When i tried concatenating the individual chunk dataframes into one single dataframe the memory requirement shoot up to 9 GB and the process of concatenating the dataframes into one took more than 2-3 hours of time. Below is code for reference

```
chunksize = 1000
list_of_dataframes = []
count=0

for df in pd.read_csv(path_to_large_csv_file, chunksize=chunksize):
    # process your data frame here
    # then add the current data frame into the list
    list_of_dataframes.append(df)
    count = count + 1
    if count%100==0 or count>11935:
        print(count, end=" ")
        print("*", end=" ")
print(count)

d = pd.DataFrame()

for sm in list_of_dataframes:
    d = pd.concat([d,sm],axis=0)
    del sm

d.head()
```

Edit:
I tried pd.concat() as suggested in comment by @julaine and increased memory of my VM from 10GB to 32GB. Following observations:

- The 3GB CSV file when read as pandas dataframe is taking 12GB in memory
- pd.concat is actually very fast `d = pd.concat(list_of_dataframes, axis=0, ignore_index=True, copy=False)`

Now my question is why a 3 GB CSV file is taking whooping 12 GB in memory when read as pandas dataframe ? and How can i reduce it ?

Comment: please state the version of python and jupyter and avoid saying 'latest version' so that future readers get more benefit from this.

Comment: and include your pandas version

Comment: I do not know the source of your problem, but you can probably make your code a lot faster by using `pd.concat(list_of_dataframes, axis=0)` directly instead of using the loop as it wont create intermediate dataframes.

Comment: I tried pd.concat() and increased memory of my VM from 10GB to 32GB. Following are my observations:

The 3GB CSV file when read as pandas dataframe is taking 12GB in memory
pd.concat is actually very fast ```d = pd.concat(list_of_dataframes, axis=0, ignore_index=True, copy=False)```
Now my question is why a 3 GB CSV file is taking whooping 12 GB in memory when read as pandas dataframe ? and How can i reduce it ?

Comment: Well, a CSV files are text files and Pandas need intermediate data structures because it does not know the shape of the input. Taking 4x the input file space seems perfectly reasonable to me. However, loading a 3 GiB CSV is clearly not reasonable. CSV files are not meant to contains a huge amount of data. They are made to store small files in a human readable way. Humans cannot read 3 GiB of data. It is like running a program in debug mode and complaining about its speed. There are other file formats that are far more efficient to load and more compact (e.g. Parquet/Feather).

Comment: Note that once in memory values like floating-point value can be significantly bigger than in a CSV. For exemple, "1.5" takes 3 bytes, while a double-precision floating-point value takes 8 bytes. You can reduce the memory overhead if you specify small input types for the columns of your dataframe. It will not only take less space, but also generally be faster. Defaults types are big (so slow) for users not to encounter issues. Besides note that strings should be avoided for sake of performance.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I will try feather as file format and use smaller data types to reduce memory. Will post results here

Comment: @JérômeRichard while staying away from 3GB csv-files is generally a good idea, there is still another issue going on, because the program only takes an hour on the VM and a minute on the local machine.

Comment: @julaine Right, but if there is not enough memory on the VM (or close to), the *swap memory* can make this far much slower. Indeed, the VM is supposed to have 10 GiB while the script appears to take more than that. Besides, it is not clear if VM is shared with other users or running even locally (10 GiB VM on a 8 GiB local machine does not make much sense, and in fact 10 GiB of RAM is very unusual for a non-shared VM since DIMM have generally a power of two size). Not to mention the OS takes often ~2 GiB of RAM. I guess the local machine has a SSD and not the VM.

Comment: @JérômeRichard you are right a 10GB VM on an 8GB computer will be slow. I assumed the VM was on a remote-machine because that is my current setup but there is nothing in the post to indicate that.

Comment: @KuldeepJangir please tell us how feather worked for you

Comment: I was unable to use feather so far.But i tried deleting two unwanted columns and making a uniform data across one column to integer. This reduced memory by a lot and the disk size was reduced by 300 MB. I will post further analysis once i am done